# There might be a site for customized eclipse downloads

Tags: eclipse, customization

Anyone who heared about .customized eclipse.
Where you can preselect packages before the download.

thx.. Sven

Comment: Try, uhm, google? What about just eclipse.org and the sites it links to?

Answer (score 1):

You could download basic version of Eclipse and then install only the plugins you need one by one.

Official [download site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php) for the project also has some custom builds that might satisfy your needs.

There is also [Easy Eclipse](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/home/). Which is a site that custom builds Eclipse for certain tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pulse](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/) and [Yoxos On Demand](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start).

[Pulse](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/) works by downloading small application to your computer. Using this application you can select packages to be installed (Pulse takes care of dependencies), and then Pulse downloads everything to your computer. Pulse can manage several customized Eclipse applications on your computer. (If you want to add additional software to your Pulse-managed appliation, you need to use Pulse only. I think that downloading plugins from within Eclipse doesn't work, but I am not sure at the moment)

[Yoxos](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start) works differently. It is entirely web-based, there is no prior download. You select your packages on the web, and Yoxos builds resulting eclipse.zip to download. This zip file looks like normal distributed eclipse, but has additional packages bundled.

Both Yoxos and Pulse can be used for free for personal usage.